# What is the difference between displayName(); and return displayName;?

Tags: javascript, closures

I am an aspiring front-end developer. I was reading an MDN article about **closure in JavaScript**. The MDN article used the following two code examples to explain the basic concept. Though I understood the basic concept, I have the following doubt.

What is the difference between `displayName();` and `return displayName` ?

```
function init() {
  var name = 'Mozilla'; // name is a local variable created by init
  function displayName() { // displayName() is the inner function, a closure
    alert(name); // use variable declared in the parent function    
  }
  displayName();    
}
init();
```

**

```
function makeFunc() {
  var name = 'Mozilla';
  function displayName() {
    alert(name);
  }
  return displayName;
}

var myFunc = makeFunc();
myFunc();
```

Comment: `displayName();` calls the function that `displayName` references. `return displayName;` returns the reference, in this case making `myFunc` reference the same function.

Comment: `displayName` is the variable name, in that case, a function and `displayName()` is how you call a function passing zero params.

Comment: When you use `()` you are calling the function whereas returning **without** `()` is passed as a reference.

Comment: This may help: [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: @ Paulpro I understand that we call/execute a function by putting paranthesis and a semi-colon after the function name, which is the case with displayName();. But what is the use of "returning a reference"? What does it mean? Can you pls. elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: I didn't get notified because of the space between `@` and `Paulpro`. Make sure not to put a space after `@` if you want to notify people.

Comment: You probably understand what `return name;` would do, right? That would return a string, because the value of `name` is a string. `return displayName;` returns a reference to a function because the value of `displayName` is a reference to a function.

Comment: The reason it's a reference is because functions are objects in JavaScript and variables can only store references to objects in JavaScript. The distinction is important because objects (hence functions) are not copied. `var a = {}; var b = a; var c = {}; console.log( a == b ); console.log( a == c ); console.log( b == c );`

Comment: @Paulpro Thanks a lot. Yours answers have been helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case it is executing the function , while in second case `makeFunc` is returning another function.Check the `console.log`. That is the reason there is a `()` after `myFunc()` which will execute the function returned from `makeFunc`

```js
function init() {
  var name = 'Mozilla';

  function displayName() {
    alert(name);
  }

  displayName();
}
init();

function makeFunc() {
  var name = 'Mozilla';

  function displayName() {
    alert(name);
  }
  // this is returning a function
  console.log(displayName)
  return displayName;
}

var myFunc = makeFunc();
// since it is returning a function it is getting executed ony after adding () with it
myFunc();
```

Comment: so, these two code examples are structured differently but give the same output. I am wondering what is the need to write the second example, which is a bit lengthier than the first one?

Comment: @hemanta The example would be much more interesting if `name` was a parameter of `makeFunc`: `function makeFunc(name) { ...`. Also remove the first line of makeFunc that sets the value of name to `Mozilla`.

Comment: @hemanta Then you can do `var mFunc = makeFunc('Mozilla'); var sFunc = makeFunc('StackOverflow'); sFunc(); mFunc(); sFunc(); sFunc(); mFunc();`

Answer (score 0):

> What's the difference between displayName() and return displayName?

The difference is that the first is *invoking* the function `displayName` while the second is *returning* it. To see an example of what that means:

```
const log = () => console.log('I was invoked!')

const getLog = () => {
  return log
}

const doLog = () => {
  log()
}
```

We have some function that, when *invoked*, prints to the console. We also have two other functions, one that *returns* `log` and one that *invokes* it. When we call `getLog()`, we don't see anything printed to the console. When we call `doLog()`, we do.

Another point is that `getLog` *returns the value* of `log`. So we can do this as well:

```
const logByDifferentName = getLog()
```

which wouldn't cause `log` to be invoked but assign it to another value.